# Adding <base href="/"> In AJS apps

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I am unable to add the following in my index.html at dist folder :

```
 <base href="/">
```

after head tag. How can I do it using grunt task?

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: Just manually stick it in your template for index.html?

Comment: no..i want it to be included during build not during dev. So how can i write grunt task for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml) to only add the `<base>`-element after building by using the `template`-block

```
<!-- build:template
<base href="/">
/build -->
```

Notice how the template block is commented out until you process your files with `grunt-processhtml`. You can optionally add template values to if you want to change the `href`-values to something other than the root.

```
<!-- build:template
<base href="/<%= basehref %>">
/build -->
```

The config:

```
  processhtml: {
    build: {
      options: {
        data: {
          basehref: ''
        }
      },
      files: {
        'dist/index.html': ['index.html']
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: where should i add this config? In which file? I tyried adding in gruntfile.js and it throws error

Comment: @Smitha did you remember to install it with `npm install grunt-processhtml`? What was the error?

Comment: now its not throwing error but its not adding the task. i did install process html

Comment: Could you edit in (the relevant parts of) your Gruntfile, would be helpful. Also try running grunt with --verbose-flag (grunt --verbose) to see more helpful output.